# Deleting template pointer in array of undetermined size causes SIGABRT

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, memory, vector

```
template <class T>
class Vector {
    int pos = 0;
    int chunkSize;

    T** p = new T*;
public:
    Vector(int chunkSize = 1000) {
        this->chunkSize = chunkSize;
        p[0] = new T[chunkSize];
        std::cout << &p[0] << std::endl;
    }
    ~Vector() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pos / chunkSize; i++) {
            std::cout << &p[i] << std::endl;
            delete [] p[i];
        }
    }

    void pushBack(T val);
    void display();
};

template<class T>
void Vector<T>::pushBack(T val) {
    p[pos / chunkSize][pos % chunkSize] = val;
    if (++pos % chunkSize == 0)
        p[pos / chunkSize] = new T[chunkSize];
}

template<class T>
void Vector<T>::display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        std::cout << p[i / chunkSize][i % chunkSize] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I was tinkering with some code today, and came up with the above. What I am trying to do is create something resembling a vector, by using fixed sized arrays, and just creating more as I need.

I usually program in Java, so memory management isn't my forte, and I am not sure that what I am doing is entirely okay. The vector is created fine, and I can add any number of values to it just fine. I can also display them, without issue, using the display function above. However, the destructor throws a SIGABRT when trying to delete any element, and that is why I am here, I don't know why I can't free memory I have allocated and have access to, although I guess one possibility is that I am writing and reading from memory I should not have access to. Those two cout statements print the same address for the 0th element, which I used to check that I was consistently looking at the same memory address.

Could someone explain to me either how to delete the elements properly, or why what I am doing is a huge mistake?

EDIT: The main class calls this code as follows.

```
int main() {
    Vector<int> vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        vec.pushBack(i);
    vec.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I am not sure that what I am doing is entirely okay" - it's not, in fact it's somewhat incomprehensible. Which C++ textbook are you learning this stuff from?

Comment: No offense meant, but this is a complete mess, I'm not sure where to start beyond: "almost everything is wrong in every way".

Comment: Please post a complete working example which can be copy-pasted and run. The code you're using this object from can affect the program execution.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm not pulling this from any textbook, I just tried this until the compiler stopped complaining. It just seems odd that I could write and read the memory I allocated, and I don't understand why, which is why I am asking.

Comment: Before you do anything non-trivial in C++, and managing dynamic allocation is non-trivial, I strongly recommend familiarizing yourself with [The Rule of Three and its friends Five and Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: If you are not using a good textbook, you are not going to learn C++ properly.

Comment: In C/C++ you can try to read/write any memory you like: `int *a = 123456; *a=5;`. But this will probably cause crash, or even worse, if it's your application's RAM it will succeed overwriting whatever is there.

Comment: @NeilButterworth This is not for learning purposes. I understand this is unorthodox code, and I would not use this anywhere, which is why it is confined to my test file. I am curious as to why I can write one billion integers to memory that I should not have access to, and without it impacting my system.

Comment: Important note: Compiler guarantees syntactically correct code, not logical. As an example, [Jabberwocky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky) would compile if there was such a thing as an English compiler but it still makes no sense. Start from logic and and don't change code to less logical just to make it compile. It still won't work

Comment: @user4581301 I understand compilers don't check logic, I have run out of bounds many times, and suffered other lapses in logic previously that caused program failure. The above code does work. I can run it, and read and write to memory just fine, without a hitch.

Comment: "This is not for learning purposes"  - how can you write C++ code, a language you seem to know almost nothing about, without learning something about it first?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I apologize for the confusion. Of course I have learnt something from asking the question, so it is for learning purposes, what I meant was that that code was not meant to teach me 'proper' C++, since the handling of the memory is intentionally improper. I admit that I am no expert in C++, since I have written Java all my life. The fact that I could read and write a billion integers without interfering with anything puzzled me, since I expected something to break. Reading a book could have answered my question, but the same is true of all the questions on this site.

Comment: Read book first, ask questions later. Ignoring this simple rule explains why so many questions here get closed immediately.

Comment: @nanoandrew4 -- *What I am trying to do is create something resembling a vector,* -- [Example of a simple vector class](https://ideone.com/gZQFXB).  Also, realize that nonsense, UB code that compiles can be totally changed by the compiler unexpectedly.   Don't write nonsense code on purpose, unless you're a compiler writer.  It's just a waste of time trying to figure out "yes, this code is garbage.  Why is it doing what it's doing?"

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Fair enough, and thank you for the example, though I already drafted my own (sensible!) implementation. I'll keep my distance from nonsense code, I was simply unaware that new T* was the equivalent of new T*[1], as the accepted answer points out. Still have some knowledge holes to patch up...

Comment: @NeilButterworth As I mentioned in the above comment, the question stemmed from a lapse in knowledge and a mistaken assumption. I'll take your advice to heart and try to dig deeper next time I come across something like this, thank you.

Comment: "I was simply unaware that new T* was the equivalent of new T*[1]" - it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only allocate space for **one** `T*` and store that in your `p` pointer.  Once you push back `chunksize` elements, you write to `p[1]`, which (since it past the end of the memory allocated for it) results in Undefined Behavior.  Which includes running on apparently working for quite some time before it blows up.

You'll need to allocate additional space in the `p` array whenever you need to access additional elements there.

Comment: The answer is correct, but is missing some more explanation. `T** p = new T*;`. When you want an array of pointers, you need to allocate RAM **for the array of pointers themselves** and the objects they point to (Ts). You allocated space only for p[0]. You should do something like '`T** p = new T[no_of_chunks];` And when you want to use `p[no_of_chunks]` and index after that you need to allocate more pointers.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize using T* allocated space for only one pointer, I thought it might allocate undetermined space, since usually I'd have to do something such as T*[10], and thought maybe skipping the size declaration could allow me to cheat... As a sidenote, I filled it with 10 billion integers and nothing much happened... Other than segmentation fault due to running out of memory, so apparently I have a guardian angel.